# Error occurred during command execution from a CLI plugin (@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova)

Tags: cordova, ionic2

When I try do a ‘ionic cordova run android’ I am getting the below error. Can someone please suggest a solution? Please note that the app had ran successfully before previously and I guess after I updated to the latest Ionic CLI and the plugins, I have started to get this error

```
[WARN] Error occurred during command execution from a CLI plugin (@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova).
Error: Non-whitespace before first tag.
Line: 0
Column: 1
Char:
```

**After I ran with --verbose I got the below error:**

```
C:\MAPP\wemartmobile\WeMartMobile>ionic cordova run android --verbose
[DEBUG] CLI flags: { interactive: true, confirm: false }
[DEBUG] { cwd: 'C:\\MAPP\\wemartmobile\\WeMartMobile', local: true, binPath:
        'C:\\Users\\d.dutta.chowdhury\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\ionic\\bin\\ionic', libPath:
        'C:\\MAPP\\wemartmobile\\WeMartMobile\\node_modules\\ionic\\dist\\index.js' }
[DEBUG] Loading local plugin @ionic/cli-plugin-proxy
[DEBUG] Throwing PLUGIN_NOT_INSTALLED for local @ionic/cli-plugin-proxy
[DEBUG] Loading local plugin @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova
[DEBUG] Loading local plugin @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular
[DEBUG] New daemon pid: 13020
[DEBUG] Getting plugin info for ionic
[DEBUG] Checking for latest plugin version of ionic@latest.
[DEBUG] Getting plugin info for @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova
[DEBUG] Checking for latest plugin version of @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova@latest.
[DEBUG] Getting plugin info for @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular
[DEBUG] Checking for latest plugin version of @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular@latest.
[WARN] Error occurred during command execution from a CLI plugin (@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova).
Error: Non-whitespace before first tag.
Line: 0
Column: 1
Char:
[DEBUG] Error: Non-whitespace before first tag.
        Line: 0
        Column: 1
        Char:
        at error (C:\MAPP\wemartmobile\WeMartMobile\node_modules\elementtree\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:666:10)
        at strictFail (C:\MAPP\wemartmobile\WeMartMobile\node_modules\elementtree\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:692:7)
        at beginWhiteSpace
        (C:\MAPP\wemartmobile\WeMartMobile\node_modules\elementtree\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:965:7)
        at Object.write (C:\MAPP\wemartmobile\WeMartMobile\node_modules\elementtree\node_modules\sax\lib\sax.js:1006:11)
        at XMLParser.feed (C:\MAPP\wemartmobile\WeMartMobile\node_modules\elementtree\lib\parsers\sax.js:48:15)
        at ElementTree.parse (C:\MAPP\wemartmobile\WeMartMobile\node_modules\elementtree\lib\elementtree.js:271:10)
        at Object.parse (C:\MAPP\wemartmobile\WeMartMobile\node_modules\elementtree\lib\elementtree.js:584:8)
        at Function.<anonymous>
        (C:\MAPP\wemartmobile\WeMartMobile\node_modules\@ionic\cli-plugin-cordova\dist\lib\utils\configXml.js:28:28)
        at next (native)
        at fulfilled (C:\MAPP\wemartmobile\WeMartMobile\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:93:62)

C:\MAPP\wemartmobile\WeMartMobile>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your **config.xml** file, i got similar issue with sax.js due to having 
git conflict markup **<<<<<<< HEAD** inside config.xml